# Deduce argument type in template parametrized by function

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction

I have C framework that provides classic deferred callback execution API:

```
typedef void (*callback_t)(int value_1, int value_2, void* arg);

void schedule(callback_t callback, void* arg);
```

Here `arg` is arbitrary value specified by user that will be passed to the callback and other callback parameters are passed by framework. But really only last argument is used in handlers and it has to be explicitly cast from `void*`.

Thinking of how callback signature may be changed to match the real one I got to this solution:

```
template <typename TArg, void (*Callback)(TArg*)>
void run(TArg* arg)
{
    schedule([](int, int, void* arg)
    {
        Callback((TArg*)arg);
    }, arg);
}

...
void handler(int* arg)  // instead of handler(int, int, void* arg)
{
}

...
run<int, handler>(arg);     // instead of schedule(handler, arg)
```

The only problem here is that callback argument type has to be explicitly specified at `run` invocation.

Is there a way to make the compiler to deduce this type?
Ideally the execution code should be just:

```
run<handler>(arg);
```

There is another solution to initial problem - to create custom function object and pass it as user argument to native API. Then unpack it from `void*`, execute real callback and delete function object. But there are issues with action cancelling when callback is not executed. It will require much more work to be implemented correctly and I prefer to ignore it if there is a more simple way.

Comment: What speaks against `template<typename TArg> void run(void (*Callback)(TArg*), TArg* arg);` and letting template argument type deduction do the rest?

Comment: @gha.st In this case `Callback` argument needs to be stored somewhere  - so additional memory should be allocated before call to `schedule` and freed after callback invocation. I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Do you have an objection to creating an object that has to live as long as the callback is registered?  Basically, a trampoline that the callback "bounces" off of to reach your function.

Comment: @Yakk I just wonder if simple approach could work. The only ugly thing is explicit argument type. I suspect there is a way to solve this.

Comment: @frymode Well, the `void*` callback arg usually means you are persisting **some** state for your callback.  You are already doing lifetime management: do you mind changing what it is you are managing the lifetime of, from a `int*` to something else?

Comment: @Yakk The problem is this argument may even be on stack (and it often is): `Object object; schedule(action, &object); run_scheduler_loop();` I don't see simple way to introduce API wrapper transparently here. The only problem with initial API is unused arguments and untyped argument in callback. And it really just not worth it to redesign everything because of minor inconvenience.

Comment: @frymode yes, I'm asking if creating some other helper object would be acceptable.  Like `auto state = make_callback( handler ); run( state, arg );`.  As an aside, how are your callbacks unregistered?  Do you really want to restrict handler to being a global function?  I find my callbacks today tend to be lambdas.

Comment: @Yakk Even if callback is executed only once or scheduler loop is stopped manually without callbacks execution - things already look complicated. Of course it should be possible to design boost.asio like api on top of that with function objects support but I'd prefer not to for now :)

Comment: @Yakk Sorry, I read your comment not carefully and missed the point. I got it now. This approach really makes sence, and I somehow didn't think about it this way. Maybe because `state` looks a bit too abstract, but this concept solves lifetime issues in an elegant way. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Yakk And as for how callbacks registered and executed, I didn't really think it matters much and tried to explain they are executed once or never. They are canceled jut by terminating worker loop, nothing complex there.

Answer (score 1):

Every once in a while the Preprocessor actually can come in handy:

```
#define myRun(fun, arg) (::run<::std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(arg)>, fun>(arg))
```

Note that this will *not* evaluate `arg` or `fun` multiple times. The result is also a parenthesized expression (and not something more icky like a declaration) and thus behaves just like an ordinary function call.

Answer (score 0):

Different approach using std::bind (couldn't test though):

```
typedef void (*callback_t)(int value_1, int value_2, void *arg);

void schedule(callback_t callback, void *arg)
{
}

template <typename TArg>
void run(void (*Callback)(TArg *), TArg *arg)
{
    // needs to be freed
    std::function<void()> *bound = new std::function<void()>(std::bind(Callback, arg));

    schedule([](int, int, void *arg)
    {
        std::function<void()> &f = *(std::function<void()> *)arg;
        f();
    }, bound);
}

void foo(int *a)
{
}

int main()
{
    int *arg = nullptr;
    run(foo, arg);
}
```

Comment: Write the body of `run` and realize some additional work has to be done.

Comment: @Axalo `callback_t` comes from C API so it is defined as pain function that capturing lambda cannot be converted to.

Comment: @Axalo `::std::function<void(int, int, void*)>` cannot be (reasonably) passed to a C function, as it is a C++ type.

Comment: @Axalo I obviously meant asynchronous callback execution. Sorry if it was not clear from the question. In that case that function object needs to be allocated on heap and freed after it is invoked. The question is how to make alternative approach to be more convenient to use.

Comment: @frymode edited again. You would need to find a way of freeing the `bound`s though. But that shouldn't be a problem. Perhaps after `f()`;

Comment: @Axalo Agree, this is possible approach. I mentioned it at the end of the question but I wondered if it is possible to force compiler to deduce that argument type in a solution that is much more simple.

Comment: @frymode As gha.st has shown us, yes there is a simpler solution. But it's ugly and it's polluting the global namespace unnecessarily.

Comment: @Yakk could you please say where

Comment: @Yakk you haven't read my previous comments, have you? Anyway, I have added the delete so people not reading the comments won't think there is a leak in my solution.

Comment: Your solution now assumes that the callback will be called exactly once, no more, no fewer.  This seems dangerous, and not guaranteed by the OP: in fact, the OP explicitly mentions the possibility the callback is cancelled and never runs.

Comment: @Yakk yes it was just a suggestion, because I don't know what happens exactly inside schedule.